How to rearrange the list order of system tray icons on Win11?
After Win11 22H2, it is no longer possible to use TB-BUTTONCOUNT to obtain any information about the system tray. Microsoft has rewritten the taskbar UI using Xaml. I tried to find a new solution, and then I noticed in the registry that the value key "UIOrderList" in the "HKEY-CURRENT-USER\Control Panel\NotifyIconSettings" path may be related to the order of icons. When I manually drag the icon, this data is changed. I tried to modify the list, but obviously Explorer will not immediately be aware of the changes here (it will take effect after restarting Explorer). What is the way to make it take effect immediately? I tried stack tracing and debugging to find that the module for modifying the registry is Taskbar.dll located in the System32 directory. Any assistance in reverse engineering will be effective, thank you, anyone.
UIOrderList Registry
The "UIOrderList" structure contains 8-byte aligned TRAYNOTIFYICONIDs (little-endian), which correspond to the sub key names (in this case, decimal values) in the "HKEY-CURRENT-USER\Control Panel\NotifyIconSettings" path, representing the order of different icons.
Registry changes monitored through API
Expect to analyze the solution to the problem from the perspective of message processing or reverse engineering of the Taskbar.dll module.

look for https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/installer/util/taskbar_util.cc and https://geelaw.blog/entries/msedge-pins/

@RbMm First of all, thank you for your prompt. I have read the blog and examples you provided, and it seems that they are related to the taskbar pin. However, what troubles me is the order of changing the system tray icons (application icons in the system notification area). I hope this is related to the fixed pin on the taskbar, but I can't be sure. Is there any more detailed help in resolving UIOrderList, or is there anything I missed?

Yes, i mistake and wrong read question. This is really for taskbar pin
